# Turtle Graphics: Repeating Squares

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to create a loop that takes an input by a user and draws however many squares but it increases the size of the squares with each loop, however 2 sides are stay connected.  I'll include the graphic to better explain.

[image]

```
    import turtle

squares = 1
while squares >= 1:
    squares = int(input('How many squares would you like drawn?:'))
    if squares == 0:
        print("You must have at-least 1 square.")
        squares = int(input('How many squares would you like drawn?:'))
    else:
        for count in range(squares):
            turtle.forward(30)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(30)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(30)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(30)
            turtle.left(90)


turtle.done()
```

Comment: Do you have a *question*? So far you've just given us your homework assignment and some code without explaining what the problem is.

Comment: question is how to get it to increase the size while keeping the squares on the same line.  Every thing i have tried sofar either builds one square on top of the other or they just go all over the place.

Comment: You seem to be drawing the squares all the same size - maybe that's not a good idea? But SO isn't here to complete your homework for you, please review the material in the [help].

Comment: not asking anyone to complete my homework, its an exercise that I am trying to complete in the book, along with the rest of them, however when I go stuck on this one I figured maybe someone could help.  If you aren't sure how to do it then that is fine, maybe someone else has encountered this issue before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input request and the drawing logic ought to be separated.
Here is one approach that returns the turtle at the start at each turn, after increasing the side length.

```
import turtle

num_squares = 3
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.pendown()
side = side_unit = 30

while True:
    try:
        num_squares = int(input('input the number of squares'))
    except ValueError:
        print("please enter an integer")
    if num_squares > 3:
        break

for sq in range(1, num_squares + 1):
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(side)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(side)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(side)
    t.left(90)
    side = side_unit + 3 * sq  # increase the size of the side

    t.goto(0,0)                # return to base

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Ahhh, thats what was boggling my mind. I was either drawing squares straight up on each other or slicing through the previous square  when trying to return back to the start.  Couldn't figure out how increase the size, thank you soooo much.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for @ReblochonMasque's solution to finish ***drawing*** 100 squares, there's plenty of time to implement an alternate, faster solution based on ***stamping***.

The first thing to note is in the provided instructions it says to draw 100 squares to create the design in the figure, but that figure consists of just under 50 squares.  It's also been scaled in some non integral fashion which makes it appear to have different line thicknesses.

Let's focus on the spirt of the problem rather than the example.  The OP had a 1 square minimum so I've preserved that.  This solution also naturally tends to center the square on the window:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

DELTA = 3
MINIMUM = DELTA * 2
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

num_squares = -1

while num_squares < 1:
    try:
        num_squares = int(input('Input the number of squares: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("please enter an integer.")

    if num_squares < 1:
        print("You must have at least 1 square.")

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle("square", visible=False)
turtle.fillcolor("white")

for size in range(((num_squares - 1) * DELTA) + MINIMUM, MINIMUM - 1, -DELTA):
    turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() + DELTA/2, turtle.ycor() - DELTA/2)
    turtle.shapesize(size / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

This is clearly not the kind of solution the OP was looking for, but maybe next time a problem like this comes up, it might be one the OP will at least consider.

[image]

Comment: Nice moiré effect @cdlane